# How to write a JPQL query to select the data from two tables that returns full set of records from the first one

Tags: spring-data-jpa, jpql

I'm dealing with a Spring-Boot app with JPA on board and the database in Postgres.

The current goal is to retrieve the entries from one table along with some aggregated statistics from another one.

In traditional SQL I would use a statement *LEFT JOIN (subquery)* like the following:

```
SELECT d.*, stats.avg_salary
FROM departments d
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT e.dep_id, avg(e.salary) AS avg_salary
  FROM employees e
  GROUP BY e.dep_id) stats
ON (d.id = stats.dep_id)
```

And now I need something similar in JPQL.

The point is to retrieve **all** the departments including those that have employees with NULL salary, or having no employees at all.

The query I've created so far (see below) returns only the departments having a match (it works like *INNER JOIN*), but I need it to include also the entries with NULL average salary.

```
@Query("SELECT d, avg(e.salary) "
  +"FROM Department d, Employee e "
  +"WHERE (e.department = d) "
  +"GROUP BY d")
public List<Tuple> getDepartmentsStats();
```

What is the most elegant way to write such query in JPQL?

**The solution I've selected**

When my queries became a bit more sophisticated, I realized that the most suitable way is to use native queries and projections, as *@Dirk Deyne* suggested.

I would say, this keeps the entity-classes and the data model clear and simple, whilst gives freedom to build complicated queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use a native query like

```
  @Query(value =
    "SELECT d.name, stats.avg_salary " + 
    "FROM department d " + 
    "LEFT JOIN " + 
    "  (SELECT e.department_id, avg(e.salary) AS avg_salary " + 
    "  FROM employee e " + 
    "  GROUP BY e.department_id) stats " + 
    "ON (d.id = stats.department_id)", nativeQuery = true
    )
  public List<Tuple> getNativeDepartmentsStats();
```

and if `Department` has a close relationship with `Employee` like

```
@Entity
class Department {
  @Id @GeneratedValue
  Long id;
  String name;
  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "department")
  Set<Employee> employees;
...
```

then you can use pure JPQL like

```
  @Query("SELECT d , avg(e.salary) FROM Department d left join d.employees e GROUP BY d")
  public List<Tuple> getFullDepartmentsStats();
```

probably a better solution is to use Projection like

```
interface DepAvg {
  Department getDepartment();
  Long getAverage();
}
```

then you can use something like

```
  @Query(value =
      "SELECT dep.name Department, stats.Average Average " + 
      "FROM department dep " + 
      "LEFT JOIN " + 
      "  (SELECT e.department_id, avg(e.salary) AS Average " + 
      "  FROM employee e " + 
      "  GROUP BY e.department_id) stats " + 
      "ON (dep.id = stats.department_id)", nativeQuery = true
      )
    public List<DepAvg> getDepartmentsAvg();
```

Comment: One question about the first option (native query). If I put "SELECT d.*, stats.avg_salary FROM ...", I get a org.hibernate.MappingException. Is there a way to explicitly define the mapping Department+Double for the result?

Comment: org.hibernate.MappingException can have multiple causes... Is your entity annotated with ```javax.persistence.Entity```? Does your application start? Do you only get the exception when you call the query?

Comment: Yes, the entity class is annotated as _@Entity_ and _@Table(name='...')_. The application starts successfully (so the JPQL is somehow translated to SQL). The exception happens, when I call the query method. It says: _No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 1111; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 1111_

Comment: are you using some special types in your mappings? like UUID?

Comment: Besides usual types, my entity has _com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Point_. My _spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect_ is defined as _org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.postgis.PostgisDialect_. Everything related to this entity works fine in JPQL queries. But not in the native ones.